# I got Routing Error in ActionController until restart rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, rails-routing, actioncontroller

I want to include module `MultipartForm` to `ApplicationController` to extend some functionality for all controllers with methods from this module.

Every time I made a change in any controllers in app I got this error. So I have to restart my app. Then it's work fine.

From `development.log`

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::MultipartForm):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8:in `<class:ApplicationController>'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/artists_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

My `application_controller.rb` is:

```
require_relative '../../lib/multipart_form'

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  #protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  include MultipartForm

  private

  def default_serializer_options
    {root: false}
  end

end
```

My `multipart_form.rb` is:

```
module MultipartForm
  # Use in controller like: send_multipart_form(:artist => artist_params)
  def send_multipart_form(send_params)
    _method = params && params[:_method] ? params[:_method].to_sym : :post
    RestClient.send _method, ActiveResource::Base.site.to_s + related_url, send_params
  end

  private

  def related_url
    _controller_path = params && params[:controller] ? params[:controller] : ""
    _id = params && params[:id] ? params[:id] : ""
    "#{_controller_path}/#{_id}"
  end
end
```

Can you suggest a solution how to extend controllers functionality with module and not need to restart server when any code changes. How to do it in best rails 4 way?

Some info:

```
Rails server => WEBrick 1.3.1
Rails version => 4.0.2
Env => development
Ruby version => ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: `application_controller.rb:8`
show me this line please

Comment: line 8 is: `include MultipartForm`

Comment: try to place `mulitpart_form.rb` under `you_app_name/lib/extras/` directory.

Comment: It wasn't help. I got the same `uninitialized constant ApplicationController::MultipartForm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to use initializer. Create `load_extensions.rb` in rails `initializers` dir
load_extensions.rb is:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  include MultipartForm
end
```